# How to construct two disjoint set with $|A\bigcup B|_e < |A|_e + |B|_e$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$|\cdot|_e$ is lebesgue outer measure.

I did a relative exercise that

there exist $E_1,E_2,...,E_k$,.... disjont set with $$|\bigcup_{k}E_k|_e < \sum_{k}|E_k|_e $$

In this case, we can give nonmeasurable set E in [0,1] with 0<$|E|_e<1$ and let $r_k$ is rational number in(0,1).

Define $E_k$={$ x+r_k|x\in E $}

then $$|\bigcup_{k}E_k|_e \le 2< \sum_{k}|E_k|_e =\infty$$

but the case is infinite,how do I construct two disjoint set with $|A\bigcup B|_e < |A|_e + |B|_e$

Comment: This isn't true. One of the defining properties of a measure is countable additivity over disjoint unions. Your example is false because a nonmeasurable set does not have a defined measure by definition.

Comment: we can not have the actual measure of nonmeasurale set.But we can find its range. And for any set E ,we will say the lebesgue measure of set is $|E|_e$,the nonmeasurale set also cantained in the collection of any set,right?
If my concept is false,please give me suggestion,thank you!

Comment: sorry ,|$\cdot $| is lebesgue outer measure.

Answer (score 1):

We can show the existence of $A\subset [0,1]$ such that for any uncountable closed $f\subset [0,1]$ we have $f\cap A\ne \emptyset \ne f$ \ $A.$ So the inner measures of $S$ and of $[0,1]$ \ $A$ are each $0$. So, with $B=[0,1]$ \ $A$ we have $|A|_e=|B|_e=|A\cup B|_e=1.$

To obtain $A,$ we use the following: Let $|S|$ denote the cardinal of any set $S.$ Let $c=|\mathbb R|.$ Let $F$ be the family of closed uncountable subsets of $[0,1].$ Then $|F|=c$ and  $\forall f\in F\;(|f|=c).$

We take $c$ to be the cardinal ordinal, that is, $c$ is the least ordinal with a bijection to  $\mathbb R.$  Let $F=\{f_a: a\in c\}.$ Define $\{(u(a),v(a)):a\in c\}$ recursively as follows: Let $u(a)$ and $v(a)$ be unequal members of $f_a$ \ $(\{u(b): b\in a\}\cup \{v(b): b\in a\}).$

Now let $A=\{u(a):a\in c\}.$ For any $f_a\in F$ we have $u(a)\in  f_a\cap A.$ And we have $v(a)\in f_a \cap ([0,1]$ \ $A )= f_a\cap B.$